# C# HttpWebRequest Get Total Page Size

Tags: c#, .net

Hello I am trying to get the entire total page size with HttpWebRequest from images scripts etc. I need to calculate the total trafic of a web page if one user visits the page via web browser. The content length brings me the length of the content in byte size. It is actualy the document length. But i need to get all the traffic also from Images and scripts

This is my Code So far

```
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);            
request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("proxy", true);
request.Proxy.Credentials = cred;
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5";
using (HttpWebResponse requestresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Headers = requestresponse.Headers;
                    Url = requestresponse.ResponseUri;                    
                   int ContentLength;

                    if (int.TryParse(response.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out ContentLength))
                    {                    
                        //This is One way i get the content leangth
                        WebPageSize = ContentLength;
                    }
                        //This is another way i get the content leangth
                    WebPageSize = request.ContentLength;
                    return ProcessContent(requestresponse);                   
                }
```

Also I the header content length is not guaranteed that the server will respond it back.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what you mean by traffic on page?do you want to count total visitors of your webpage?

Comment: No i need to check if one user logs in the page then how much traffic will the page handle in order to load totaly. I need the Total size of the webpage with its images and its javascripts and css and all its loadig trafic needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to check the size once why don't you try using the Net panel of Firebug (Firefox extension) or the equivalent tool of other browsers? It will tell you the size off all the requests performed while loading a webpage.

Comment: because i need to make a tool for many pages in an automatic way

Comment: So regarding your code, after you download the html page (just call GetResponseStream of the HttpWebResponse objecy) you can parse the html and get also the relevant resources (css, javascripts, images..).

Comment: Yes this is one option, to parse all the the resources one by one.
But i was thinking about the webBrowser control, is there some posibility that this control can calculate the total size of the content images js that were parsed??

Answer (score 0):

If you are the one doing the measurement and can guarantee there will be no other network traffic, you can try the following:

Get TotalBytesReceived from IPv4Statistics

Open the page in WebBrowserControl and wait until all resources are loaded.

Get the total bytes again.

From those two numbers, you can calculate the total size.

Here is an article about working with IPv4Statistics:

http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2008/02/06/how_to_calculate_network_bandwidth_speed_in_c_/